# jQuery toggle span text not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, accordion

My Structure is like this : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgwj3kbk/)

I have been referring to various similar questions that the other asked but those solutions are not working for me.

So what I wanted is when I clicked on "Show+", the following content will show and the text will change from "Show+" to "Hide-" which they can be toggled.

I am trying to use if function to achieve this but not working...

```
if($(this).find('.expand').text()=="Show+"){
  $(this).find('.expand').text("Hide-");
}else{
  $(this).find('.expand').text("Show+");
}
```

Does anyone get any solution with this?? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited from your example. Try this.
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma0f4eL2/)

```
$('.title .expand').click(function(){
  $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").toggle();
  if($(this).text()=="Show+"){
    $(this).text("Hide-");
  }else{
    $(this).text("Show+");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/sgwj3kbk/1/

```js
$(function(){
  $('.title .expand').click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").slideToggle("fast", function(){
      if($('.dropdown').css('display') == 'block'){
        $('.expand').text("Hide-");
      }else{
        $('.expand').text("Show+");
      }
    });  
  })
});
```

```css
.title{
  background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.dropdown{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="title">
    <span class="expand">Show+</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    Content ..... XXX
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `slideToggle` instead of `toggle`.

`slideToggle` will provide animation effect.

One more solution with few more animation https://jsfiddle.net/sgwj3kbk/2/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of slidetoggle. However this will affect the other div with same name when clicking. Anyway I have already learnt about that I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

remove `.find('.expand')` from your code as `$(this)` is reference of class `expand`

```js
$(function(){
 $('.title .expand').click(function(){
   $(this).closest("div").next(".dropdown").toggle();
    
    if($(this).text()=="Show+"){
     $(this).text("Hide-");
    }else{
     $(this).text("Show+");
    }
  })
});
```